# Trouble selecting a certain element

Tags: python, css-selectors, lxml

I've written a css selector to select a specific element from a webpage. Upon execution I can see that my selector is able to locate "Genre:" but I want it's value which is in this case "Drama". How can I do so ?

I've tried with:

```
.mdif li b
```

Elements within which the item is:

```
<div class="mdif">
<ul>
    <li><b>Genre:</b>Drama</li>
    <li><b>Quality:</b>1080p</li>
    <li><b>Screen:</b>1920x1080</li>
    <li><b>Size:</b>1.67G</li>
    <li><b>Rating:</b>6.1/10</li>
    <li><b>Peers:</b>17</li>
    <li><b>Seeds:</b>0</li>
</ul>
<a href="/movie/55000/download-lake-mungo-2008-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html" class="small button orange" target="_blank" title="Download Lake Mungo (2008) 1080p YIFY Torrent">Download</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried `.mdif > li > b` ? It means that you select a child element.

Comment: can you explain further? What do you want to do with CSS?

Comment: @D.Simon it wouldn't work, if you use `>` you have to take consideration of parents. so you have to revise it like this: `.mdif > ul > li > b`

Comment: Wrap values in `span` and use this selector: `.mdif li > span`

Comment: Thanks jackjop, for your comment. Yes, at this point I need to explain. I would like to use this selector in my script to parse the value of "Genre:" which is "Drama".

Comment: I'm assuming based on your previous question that this is also an lxml question and not a CSS question. Please tag your questions correctly, otherwise people will mistakenly believe your question is about styling with CSS and answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks  BoltClock for you suggestion. Should I tag my question only with lxml or css as well?

Comment: I've updated the tags for you - I recommend python and lxml. I would avoid css, otherwise users who are subscribed to the css tag will assume you're writing a stylesheet. css-selectors is OK - it's a very niche tag.

Comment: Thanks  BoltClock for your suggestion. I will abide by next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Here is the complete code.

Html elements which have been pasted in the post above as well:

```
html = '''
<div class="mdif">
<ul>
    <li><b>Genre:</b>Drama</li>
    <li><b>Quality:</b>1080p</li>
    <li><b>Screen:</b>1920x1080</li>
    <li><b>Size:</b>1.67G</li>
    <li><b>Rating:</b>6.1/10</li>
    <li><b>Peers:</b>17</li>
    <li><b>Seeds:</b>0</li>
</ul>
</div>
'''
```

The script:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(html)
for items in root.cssselect(".mdif li"):
    item = items.cssselect("b")[0].tail.strip()
    print(item)
```

The result:

```
Drama
1080p
1920x1080
1.67G
6.1/10
17
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply needed styles to `.mdif li` and reset this styles for `.mdif li b`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  color: #ccc;
}

ul li b {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><b>Title: </b>some text 1</li>
  <li><b>Title: </b>some text 2</li>
  <li><b>Title: </b>some text 3</li>
  <li><b>Title: </b>some text 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is correct, and will be the best way to go about it (no need to resort to scripts ^_^) - but I will suggest that you edit your answer to include a working example of what you mean for any potential future users who may need better context. Good luck :)

Comment: Ah perfect - nice edit. That was exactly what I meant. Good job!

Comment: @Frits: This isn't about "resorting to" scripts. The *use case* involves scripting, not styling elements.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, I see, I had misunderstood the original intent of the question (thinking it was related to styling a the second part of the element) and was happy to see an answer that provided a solution that didn't use a script to do so. Thanks for pointing out my error :)

Comment: @Frits: The question was incorrectly tagged originally, so I don't blame you.

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly been able to understand your question then using

```
var text_val = $('.mdif').children('Genre').text();
```

will help you select the value considering you have an id for each for example:

HTML:

```
<div id='first'>
    <div id='Genre'>Drama</div>
    <div id='Quality:'>1080p</div>
    <div id='Screen:'>1920x1080</div>
    <div id="Size:">1.67G</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
var text_val = $('.mdif').children('div').text();
```

You can check here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ankita_Chatterjee/8eyogwLh/)

If you are looking for something else then please specify. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.mdif li:first-child { 
  color: red;
} 

.mdif li:first-child b{
  color: #000;
}
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
} 

li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 8px;

}

.mdif li:first-child { 
  color: red;
} 

.mdif li:first-child b {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdif">
   <ul>
    <li><b>Genre:</b><span>Drama</span></li>
    <li><b>Quality:</b><span>1080p</span></li>
    <li><b>Screen:</b><span>1920x1080</span></li>
    <li><b>Size:</b><span>1.67G</span></li>
    <li><b>Rating:</b><span>6.1/10</span></li>
    <li><b>Peers:</b><span>17</span></li>
    <li><b>Seeds:</b><span>0</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="/movie/55000/download-lake-mungo-2008-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html" class="small button orange" target="_blank" title="Download Lake Mungo (2008) 1080p YIFY Torrent">Download</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="mdif">
  <ul>
    <li><b>Genre:</b><span>Drama</span></li>
    <li><b>Quality:</b><span>1080p</span></li>
    <li><b>Screen:</b><span>1920x1080</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS selector

`.mdif li span`

Answer (score 0):

See this i have selected Drama.

```css
.mdif > ul > li > i{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdif"><ul><li><b>Genre:</b><i class="one">Drama</i></li> <li><b>Quality:</b>1080p</li> <li><b>Screen:</b>1920x1080</li> <li><b>Size:</b>1.67G</li> <li><b>Rating:</b>6.1/10</li> <li><b>Peers:</b>17</li> <li><b>Seeds:</b>0</li> </ul><a href="/movie/55000/download-lake-mungo-2008-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html" class="small button orange" target="_blank" title="Download Lake Mungo (2008) 1080p YIFY Torrent">Download</a></div>
```